# How to insert a date to new column in table 2 based on product_Id and match the (product_id) in table 1 and use a column (date) to add to table 2

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

Table 1

| Id | place | expiry_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | xyz | 2022-09-12 |

Table 2 - expiry_date is the new column created in table 2. Need to fetch expiry date from table 1 where T1_id (in table 2) matches id (in table 1)

| Oid | userid | expiry_date | T1_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 123 |  | 10 |

How to fetch expiry date (table 1 and fill the new column in table 2) only if the T1_id and Id(table 1) matches

Trying

```
insert into (sql) statements 
Joins used 
Join table1.Id on table2.T1_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert statements won't allow you to change values from an existing table, they only allow you to add brand new rows to a table. In your case you may want to use an `UPDATE` statement.

In order to get matches between the two tables, you can apply a `JOIN` operation within the `UPDATE` statement, using the condition you pointed in your post description.

```
UPDATE     tab2 
INNER JOIN tab1
        ON tab1.Id = tab2.T1_id
SET tab2.expiry_date = tab1.expiry_date;
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jJQJjjyww4ntgEcJD8D7Fi/0).